# React Protected Route redirecting when it shouldn't be

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to redirect users when they aren't signed into my app, but at the moment they are redirected always. I believe I'm being redirected before the `loggedIn` variable is set, but I'm not sure how to fix this.

```
const Protected = ({ user, loggedIn, loading, children }) => {
    if (loading) {
        return null;
    }

    if (!loggedIn) {
        return <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
    }

    return children;
};
```

```
function App() {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
    const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('/me')
            .then(res => {
                setUser(res.data)
                setLoggedIn(true);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                setLoggedIn(false);
            })

        return setLoading(false);
    }, []);

    const router = createBrowserRouter([
        {
            path: '/',
            element: (
                <Protected user={user} loggedIn={loggedIn} loading={loading}>
                  <Home />
                </Protected>
            ),
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'm  guessing is happening. Please keep in mind I've never used React Router, and am not the best person to talk about this matter, but I suspect I know what's happening.

You are updating the `isLoggedIn` state when the `<App/>` component is mounted, since it is being called in a useEffect with empty dependencies array. The problem here is, you are passing the `Protected` component to be loaded in the `App` component, so `Protected` will mount before `App`, and `isLoggedIn` value will still be set as `false`, redirecting the user back to the login page.

Have a look at the code here and the console outputs:
https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-microservice-k9no52?file=/src/App.tsx